# Laravel 5.5 best way to validate API endpoint parameters

Tags: laravel, lumen, laravel-validation

**Route**

```
Route::get('attendence/{year?}/{name?}/{category?}, 'EmployeesController@users');
```

**Controller action**

```
function users($year=null, $name=null, $category= null){
}
```

My Requirement is not to throw an exception instead show a meaningful message to the user for all the following urls.

```
http://localhost:8080/2012/john/travel 
http://localhost:8080/undefined/john/travel 
http://localhost:8080/undefined/john
http://localhost:8080/john
```

**In other words, the variable year should be validated for numeric values, name, and category for alphabets.**

**N O T E:**
 I am using Laravel Lumen

Any kind of help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Validation - https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation
2. Regular Expression Constraints + Custom exception Handler - https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints
   https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#the-exception-handler

I guess the first one is quite clear. The second one, you can catch your route exception, and render the view with a meaningful message.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Please add your code to the question